# Rolling three dice and finding and graphing pdf and cdf.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose three fair dices are rolled independently, so the sample space is Ω = {(i, j, k) :
1 ≤ i, j, k ≤ 6} and all outcomes are equally likely. Let X be the random variable showing the number on the first die, i.e., X(i) = i, and let Y be the random variable defined by Y (i, j, k) = min{i, j, k}.

(a)Find the pmf and cdf of X and graph the cdf.

For this part I thought, for i; 1 ≤ i ≤ 6 there are six sample points with X(i, j, k) = i so, p_x(i)=1/6, is this one correct?

but I am not sure how to find cdf and graph it.

(b)Find the pmf and cdf of Y and graph the cdf.

for this part, {Y = 6} = {6, 6, 6)},
{Y = 5} = {(5, 6, 6),(6, 5, 6),(6, 6, 5),(6, 5, 5),(5, 6, 5),(5, 5, 6),(5, 5, 5)}, and so on. In general, for 1 ≤ i ≤ 6, there are 1 + 3(6 − i) + 3(6 − i)^2
sample points for which Y = i. Thus, pY (i) = 1+3(6−k)+3(6−k)^2/216
for 1 ≤ i ≤ 6, and could not find cdf and graph it.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Let $U, V, W$ be the outcome of each respective dice roll and $Y$ their minimum. Since $U, V, W$ are i.i.d and $Y\gt k$ iff $U\gt k$ and $V\gt k$ and $W\gt k$, it follows that
$$
P(Y\gt k) = P(U\gt k)P(V\gt k)P(W\gt k) = P(U\gt k)^3 = \frac{6-k}{6^3}\quad (1\leq k\leq 6)
$$
from which $P(Y\leq k) = 1-P(Y>k)$. For the mass function of $Y$ use the identity
$$
P(Y=k) =P(Y>k-1)- P(Y>k)
$$